# how is czech "ch" letter stored in mysql and how to get it using substr?

Tags: mysql, sql, collation

Even "ch" appears as two letters, in czech its considered as one letter and its order in alphabet is after H letter (so correct order is a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,ch,i,j (I skipped some national characters).  But when I do 
substr (colname, 1, 1) on column containing words begining with ch Im getting only "C"

this sql: SELECT SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1) AS title_truncated FROM node node  WHERE node.type in ('termin') GROUP BY title_truncated ORDER BY title_truncated ASC"

returns: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J  (so no ch).

btw database is using utf8_czech_ci

Comment: Can you create a clearer test case like `SELECT SUBSTR("xyz", 1, 1)` where "xyz" is a word beginning with "ch"? The "ch" is not technically a single character, right? But it's *regarded* as one in czech language? (Not saying that's why it shouldn't work, just to clarify)

Comment: Related: http://lists.mysql.com/internals/34384

Comment: @Peter: 'Ch' is not considered as one character in any character set. Collation is only able to handle correct ordering. Btw. same happens in MS SQL.

Comment: @Ladislav I just arrived at the same conclusion. :)

Comment: @peter: When you type on your czech keyboard how do you type 'ch'? :)

Comment: @Ladislav. yeah, of course. Problem is that Im using drupal and its views glossary mode to build alphabar for dictionary. Which of course generates alphabar without "ch", additionaly words starting with "ch" are sorted as the last ones in the C column

Comment: Actually in "KOI-8" encoding 'ch' is a special character as specified by the Czech national standard. Nut that encoding is not used anymore. The problem is that without 'ch' as a special character it is not possible to implement sorting as required by the national standard.

Answer (score 2):

`Ch` is not a character in itself in Unicode, it is a [digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_%28digraph%29).

As such, it seems impossible for a database collation to properly map the difference. What @Ladislav says in the comment, and the user in this [mySQL internals discussion,](http://lists.mysql.com/internals/34384) seems to support this.

You will probably have to work around this manually, e.g. in your example, using a `IF` clause that tests for the presence of "Ch", and returns two characters if that is the case.

Reference: [`utf8_czech_ci` collation table (mySQL 6)](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_czech_ci.html)

Answer (score 2):

Even though `ch` is considered a single sorting "letter" in Czech, it isn't considered a single "character" in any other way. It is stored and printed as two characters whenever it is encountered.

The *collation* setting in MySQL affects how strings are sorted, trying to sort individual characters is not very meaningful in many languages. E.g. `č` comes after (IIRC) `c` but `ně` and `ne` are equivalent so word ordering depends on the following letters.

I don't understand the underlying problem that you are trying to solve but I think the easiet approach might be to avoid using `substring` and to sort by `title` and only output the first "letter" if it changes when you are processing the results.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could modify your definition of `title_truncated` like this:

```
CASE SUBSTRING(title, 1, 2)
  WHEN 'ch' THEN SUBSTRING(title, 1, 2)
  ELSE SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1)
END AS title_truncated
```